# Applying identification mark on a glass trophy

Tags: stationery

I won a trophy and it is made out of glass almost entirely, except a label regarding the event on the front.

The problem is, there is no unique identification mark for it. (Like our names, the event for which we won). There are about 10-15 winners of various events and we need to submit it to our school and we would receive them back later.

Is there a way in which I could make some identification mark on it?(sentimental value)(I don't want to have it interchanged with someone else's)

I don't want to make it very obvious by writing my name,etc on paper and then sticking it on to the trophy. I also don't want to damage the label.

Comment: Can you edit your question, and add a photo of the trophy? It might give us some more ideas about where and how to add the identifying mark.

Comment: If all of them were in a box together, could you tell them apart? If they are all identical, it does not matter. Let's say you were successful. What would happen if you got one back after the ceremony and it wasn't yours (your secret mark is not there)? Would you be able to examine all the others to find yours again.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the issue is. It sounds like the awards aren't unique so why does it matter which one you get back?

Comment: Be sure that before you choose a labeling technique, you are aware that the answers are based upon the trophy being glass, as you describe. If it is something similar such as acrylic, the materials and processes good for glass may not be applicable.

Answer (score 5):

Even simpler than the clear tape mentioned in another answer:

Write or draw directly on the (bottom of) the trophy with a permanent marker, remove it with rubbing alcohol or nail polish remover when you get it back. Previously degreasing the area you are planning to write on can improve the durability of the marker.

Optional:

You can protect the marker with clear tape, but some brands are prone to leave a bit of a residue, especially if they have been exposed to warmth (think illuminated trophy-case) for some time. The alcohol or nail polish remover will help here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations!

Print your name, address, and student ID neatly and discretely on a small piece of clear cellophane tape using a fine-point permanent black marker and apply it to the base/bottom of the trophy.

An alternative is to do the same thing on the sticky side of the tape and do the same thing. Printing on that side is more resilient to being rubbed-off by handling. Many fancy transparent jar labels are printed with the ink on the adhesive inside of the label before application.

Good luck.

Comment: If you're the only person putting a mark on yours, then clear tape _without anything written on it_ would work, provided that you tell the school people handling your trophy that that's yours.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Sounds like answer #4?

Comment: @BrettFromLA "provided that you tell the school people handling your trophy that that's yours" - I would imagine that could be a problem. 10-15 trophies, possibly several different "school people" handling the trophies and one with a bit of clear tape on it. "Please collect your trophies from room 2A at the end of the day on Tuesday." Turn up and there's 3 trophies left, none of which have your random bit of tape stuck to it. The person who's picked up the wrong trophy has no idea they've picked up the wrong trophy, it's just got a bit of random tape stuck to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a mark that will be “invisible” to the casual and unknowing observer, use clear nail polish, preferably in an unobtrusive spot.

Either apply a “dot” for a 3D-effect or choose something with a different sheen, e.g. a matte top coat on a glossy trophy. Almost as good is a polish with a very light tint or even better, a bit of iridescence.

This suggestion is best for smooth, unpainted glass, on etched / rough surfaces, there’s a risk of permanent discoloration or damage.

Plus, you can’t rely on whoever dispenses the trophies to recognize the mark, so you’d either give them clear (no pun intended) instructions or be present when they get taken out of the display case.

Remove the mark with nail polish remover afterwards.